# Remove coins shadow using opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour, canny-operator

I am trying to count how many coins there are in the image using the latest version of OpenCV, but I am struggling with the shadows.

The Canny Edge detector method is being used but as you can see in the second image, it is not working as expected because of the shadows... Any ideas about how I could deal with this problem?

[image]

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
median = np.median(image)
lower = int(max(0, 0.67 * median))
upper = int(min(255, (1.33) * median))

canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, lower, upper)
contours, hierachy = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
coins = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Coins", coins)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the threshold of the edge detector? Also try to filter out the gray colors from the image.

Comment: Yes, I have played with the thresholds but it didn't help.

Comment: Managed to do it using the HoughCircle method

Comment: Yes that is a great solution in most high contrast cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the coin selection by color.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
low_H = 0
low_S = 50
low_V = 0
high_H = 255
high_S = 255
high_V = 255
frame = cv.imread('PzB9I.png')
frame_HSV = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
frame_threshold = cv.inRange(frame_HSV, (low_H, low_S, low_V), (high_H, high_S, high_V))
#         filling holes
im_floodfill = frame_threshold.copy()
h, w = frame_threshold.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
cv.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0,0), 255);
im_floodfill_inv = cv.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)
mask = frame_threshold | im_floodfill_inv
#       find contours
contours, hierachy = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
coins = cv.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv.imshow("Coins", coins)
```

[image]